# Using Luigi, how to read PostgreSQL data and then pass such data to the next task in the workflow?

Tags: python, postgresql, luigi

Using [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi), I want to define a workflow with two "stages":

- The first one reads data from PostgreSQL.
- The second one does something with the data.

Thus I've started by subclassing `luigi.contrib.postgres.PostgresQuery` and overriding host, database, user, etc as stated in the [doc](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/contrib/postgres.html).

After that, how to pass the query result to the next task in the workflow? Such next task already specifies in the `requires` method the above class must be instantiated and returned.

My code:

```
class MyData(luigi.contrib.postgres.PostgresQuery):

    host = 'my_host'
    database = 'my_db'
    user = 'my_user'
    password = 'my_pass'
    table = 'my_table'
    query = 'select *'

class DoWhateverWithMyData(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        return MyData()
```

What else is needed?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

Having a look to Luigi's code, it seems nothing is done at the `run` method of [`PostgresQuery`](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/contrib/postgres.html#PostgresQuery) with the result of the query; I mean, the query is run and that's all:

```
class PostgresQuery(rdbms.Query):
    """
    Template task for querying a Postgres compatible database

    Usage:
    Subclass and override the required `host`, `database`, `user`, `password`, `table`, and `query` attributes.
    Optionally one can override the `autocommit` attribute to put the connection for the query in autocommit mode.

    Override the `run` method if your use case requires some action with the query result.

    Task instances require a dynamic `update_id`, e.g. via parameter(s), otherwise the query will only execute once

    To customize the query signature as recorded in the database marker table, override the `update_id` property.
    """

    def run(self):
        connection = self.output().connect()
        connection.autocommit = self.autocommit
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql = self.query

        logger.info('Executing query from task: {name}'.format(name=self.__class__))
        cursor.execute(sql)

        # Update marker table
        self.output().touch(connection)

        # commit and close connection
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()


    def output(self):
        """
        Returns a PostgresTarget representing the executed query.

        Normally you don't override this.
        """
        return PostgresTarget(
            host=self.host,
            database=self.database,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            table=self.table,
            update_id=self.update_id
        )
```

I think I'll have to extend such a class with my own implementation.

**EDIT 2**

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/luigi-user/Nax5tm2QAx8) link explaining the same than my above edit.

Comment: I am confuse on why you are not just reading the data at run() level directly from postgres? Normally one would have a task writing data to SQL and a second task consuming that data. Normally, the `consume data task` would require the `write data task` to make sure the data is available in SQL. is that what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Data is already in Postgres, written by a third-party system. I just want to read and process it using a Luigi pipeline.

Comment: but why dont you just call the data in a single task in the `run()` method and then process it all at the same time? this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll finally do. I just wanted to test the `PostgresQuery` class, and to explore if it could be useful for me. Thanks!