# How to use Luigi to with specific columns of a SQL table as a target

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, etl, luigi

In Luigi, suppose I have TaskA and TaskB, which each generate a column of data to be put into table1. If I use a SQL target, Luigi wants to write to the full table it seems, but this makes adding new columns to the table a slow process. Imagine that table1 is populated with columns A and B. I want to add a new field C, which can be output by taskC, but I would prefer to write it directly into the SQL table, since otherwise I'd have to store A,B,C elsewhere, and have another task that reads them all and writes them into the table. Is there a way to do this without duplicating the database elsewhere, instead just having each task just write it's data into the appropriate columns of the SQL table?

Answer (score 1):

> If I use a SQL target, Luigi wants to write to the full table it seems

I think you misunderstood what a `Target` is. It doesn't "do things", it's just used to signal to luigi whether a `Task` has finished or not.

For what I understood, I think you were trying to use one of those `CopyToTable` tasks like [this one](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/bd10d39a284e238ac8021054de96677ff03ced04/luigi/contrib/sqla.py#L272), and those are indeed made for filling a few rows per run, so if you wish to fill a single column, you should probably create your own `Task`, and craft your own SQL query.

Luckily, you can still use a SQL target as your output, and get a connection to the database from it.

Example

Here, I used `MySqlTarget` as the target, but you could use other SQL targets.

```
class WriteSingleColumnTask(lg.Task):
    def output():
        return MySqlTarget(
            host=self.host,
            database=self.database,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            table=self.table,
            update_id=self.update_id
        )

    def  run():
        output=self.output()
        connection = output.connect()
        connection.autocommit = self.autocommit
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        query = "<YOUR QUERY FOR A SINGLE COLUMN HERE>"
        cursor.execute(sql)

        # Update marker table
        self.output().touch(connection)

        # commit and close connection
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869425/using-luigi-how-to-read-postgresql-data-and-then-pass-such-data-to-the-next-tas).